# Discord Random Character assigner

Tags: discord, discord.js

i was wanting to see if someone could help me setup a discord bot that chooses X amount of non-repeated in-game characters from a list from users in a voice channel. im kind of new to this so im not quite sure where to start to implement this

For instance say there is:
4 People in Voice Chat
I type !pickchars in our commands channel
The bot uses an embeded reply and picks A for User 1, B for User 2, and G for User 3 and so on..

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, please note that Stack Overflow is not a site to ask for free code. If you already have code, please add it to the post so we can help you. Also, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask SO help article

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I only can help you partially. What you're looking for are variables. If you want to make them it's quite easy. Use the following method to get started.

```js
var Characters = [
    'Character Name A',
    'Character Name B',
    'Character Name C',
    'Character Name D',
    //Add as much as you like and need
    ];
    
    var pick = Characters[Math.floor(Math.random()*Characters.length)];
    
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'choose')) {
    message.reply("Your character is: " + pick)
    
}
```

Note that it's completely random and it only chooses 1 Person at the Time with that Code right now. And it's possible that two people can have the same character! And note that right now it's not an embed